# Delete a webform file by clicking on its name

Tags: webforms

I added a file field to a webform. Everything works fine but I need to style the file submissions differently.

This is what I should get: the file name is displayed with an icon that allows you to delete it directly.

[image]

However, on webform, we have a checkbox next to the name of the file that must be checked and then click on the submit button so that the file is deleted.

[image]

I am able to modify this functionality but I still have a problem. In js, when we click on the file name, I check the checkbox and simulate a `mousedown on the submit button. It works fine but after the 2nd click. The first does cause an ajax call but the file is not deleted.

Do you have any idea how I could handle this?

```
$('.js-form-managed-file span.file').mousedown(function (event) {
              $(this).closest('label.option').prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);

              if ($(this).closest('label.option').prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
                  $('.js-form-managed-file .js-form-submit').mousedown();
              }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create this functionality where the user directly clicks on the name of the file he sent to delete it. With css, I was able to add a delete icon next to the file name.

The error comes from the sumit button selector (the one used to delete files after checking the checkboxes) which was targeted. By doing a `console.log(settings)`, I could see in

```
_triggering_element_name
```

that the trigger element was not (`$('.js-form-managed-file .js-form-submit').mousedown();` but `$("button[name='shop_files_remove_button']")`

So here is the working code. You have to adapt with the name of your button :

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {

  Drupal.behaviors.Contact = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      once('contact', '.js-form-managed-file').forEach(function (element) {

        $('.js-form-managed-file span.file').mousedown(function (event) {
          $(this).closest('label.option').prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        });

        var checkboxes = $('.js-form-managed-file .form-checkbox');
        checkboxes.change(function () {
          if (checkboxes.is(':checked')) {
            $("button[name='shop_files_remove_button']").mousedown();
          }
        });
      })
    }
  }

})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```